# Coding network model using Cplex

Tags: cplex

Please help me! I am a new user of CPLEX. I tried to code a network model using CPLEX. My network has 24 nodes and 38 lines (arcs) and one of my constraints has matrix multiplication. Below is what I could come up with.

I will like to know if the model is correct.

Secondly, I linked my model and data to an excel but when I run the configuration it gave an internal error. Please what causes this.

Please help me. Thanks.

```
//parameters

int B=...; //number of nodes
int L=...; //number of lines

range nodes =1..B;
range lines =1..L;

float cost_generation [nodes]= ...;
float cost_shedding [nodes]= ...;
float max_generation[nodes]= ...;
float load_demand[nodes] = ...;

float cost_transmission [lines]= ...;
float max_power_flow[lines] = ...;
float Mmatrix[1..38][1..24] = ...;

//Variables

dvar float+ G[nodes];
dvar float+ D[nodes];
dvar float+ F[lines];

minimize sum (i in nodes, k in lines)
(cost_generation[i]*G[i] + cost_transmission[k]*F[k] -     cost_shedding[i]*D[i]);

subject to {
forall (i in nodes)
0<=G[i]<=max_generation[i];

forall (i in nodes) 
-load_demand[i]<=-D[i]<=0;

forall (k in lines)
-max_power_flow[k]<=F[k]<=max_power_flow[k];

forall (k in lines, i in nodes)
 F[k]==Mmatrix[k][i]*(G[i]-D[i]);
  }
```

my data

```
B=24;
L=38;

SheetConnection my_sheet("Area 1.xlsx");

cost_generation from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Branches'!Q3:Q26");
cost_shedding from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Branches'!R3:R26");
cost_transmission from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Branches'!E3:E40");
max_generation from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Branches'!L3:L26");
load_demand from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Branches'!M3:M26");
max_power_flow from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Check'!C1:C38");
Mmatrix from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'M Matrix'!B2:Y39");
```

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing?

Comment: The error is "Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: Problem accessing the excel file". I also tried to run thesame codes on another computer and the error was "internal error, please contact IBM". Kindly assist me.

Comment: I will like to know if my coding is correct as well. Thanks

Comment: For the excel part, can you try the oil example in C:\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1263\opl\examples\opl\oil ? ("Data from spreadsheet" run configuration)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I replicated the oil example for my model and the error has been corrected. Thanks a million.
However, the solution is incorrect, zero for all decision variables.